# magento add column with coupon code in orders grid

Tags: php, magento

I have a problem with add to column with coupon code in orders grid. I used tutorial on the http://www.atwix.com/magento/customize-orders-grid/.

I copied Grid.php from `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/` to `/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/` and added this code:

```
$select->join('sales_flat_order', '`sales_flat_order`.entity_id = `main_table`.entity_id',array('coupon_code'))
```

to the function `_prepareCollection()` and added column in function `_prepareColumns()` :

```
$this->addColumn('coupon_code', array(
      'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Coupon Coded'),
           'index' => 'coupon_code'
   ));
```

But on the page Sales/Order in admin isn't show nothing. Does anyone know When could be the problem ?

Thank you for your opinion/idea.

Comment: Your code is right, check if local modules are enabled in app/etc/local.xml and try to empty the cache

Comment: Thanks. It was maybe cache and now is a new column with coupon code but if I do sort by specific Order. Show me this error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'increment_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

```
protected function _prepareCollection() { 
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order',
                'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',
                array('coupon_code' => 'coupon_code'));        
        $this->setCollection($collection);
       //For sort
        Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the code which you've added to _prepareCollection() function with the one below:

```
    $adapter = $collection->getResource()->getReadConnection();
    $subSelect = $adapter->select()
        ->from(array('sales_flat_order'), array('entity_id', 'coupon_code'));

    $collection->getSelect()
        ->join(array('order' => $subSelect), '`order`.entity_id = `main_table`.entity_id',array('coupon_code'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have ambiguous column error, try this :

```
protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
{
    if ($this->getCollection()) {
        $field = ( $column->getFilterIndex() ) ? $column->getFilterIndex() : $column->getIndex();
        $field = 'main_table.'.$field;
        if ($column->getFilterConditionCallback()) {
            call_user_func($column->getFilterConditionCallback(), $this->getCollection(), $column);
        } else {
            $cond = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();
            if ($field && isset($cond)) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($field , $cond);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```